# jquery file upload how to delete from db table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using the blueimp file upload program. The problem I am having
is in being able to update the db table when a file is deleted.

When two different users enter the same file name for an upload, it is
registered in the mysql table as two different records with the same file name and different userid's. The problem is when you go to "Delete" the file name, it deletes all files with that name. This is the code for the file upload section that works fine:

```
protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
        $index = null, $content_range = null) {
    $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
        $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
    );
    if (empty($file->error)) {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
            .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `url`, `listid`, `dorder`, `link`)'
            .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param(
        'sisssss',
            $file->name,
            $file->size,
        $file->type,
            $file->url,
            $file->listid,
            $file->dorder,
            $file->link
        );
        $query->execute();
        $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;
    }
    return $file;
}
```

The problem I am having is being able to add the "listid" variable to the
WHERE clause of the mysql query below. Listid identifies the user. This is 
the delete code that removes the filename from the db table:

```
public function delete($print_response = true) {
    $response = parent::delete(false);
    foreach ($response as $name => $deleted) {
        if ($deleted) {
            $sql = 'DELETE FROM `'
                .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=?' ;
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param(
            's', 
            $name
            );
            $query->execute();
        }
    } 
    return $this->generate_response($response, $print_response);
}
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated and I have attempted multiple solutions
to no avail.

Comment: Sounds like there is some logical problems in your setup. Allowing two different users having the same file name is questionable. Why are you doing that? Is it a valid use case? Could you simply use a folder for each user to avoid this?

Comment: You should be performing all DB record actions with a primary key and userid column

Comment: The only thing being sent to the db file is the file and user information. The actual image files are all uploaded to a specific user directory. When files are deleted the proper user files are deleted from the users image directory, no problems there. The problem is how do I add the "listid" variable to the WHERE clause of the mysql DELETE statement so the table is updated properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution and although it's a bit of a hack, it works. The upload program
is blueimp jquery-file-upload. It uses 2 php files along with a group of javascript files. The php files are index.php and uploadHandler.php.

I capture the userid in the uploadHandler.php file. I created
a global variable and assigned the userid to it.

$GLOBALS['listidDel'] = $listid;

Then in the index.php file and in the delete function, I changed the sql query
to:

$sql = "DELETE FROM `" . $this->options['db_table'] . "` WHERE `listid` = " . $GLOBALS['listidDel'] . " AND `name`= ?" ;

A bit of a hack and it does work. Now when I delete a file, it only deletes the
file name that is owned by the userid. Onward and upward.